# Difficulties with re-using a variable

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt

here is a part of my code :

```
class projet(object):

    def nameCouche(self):

        valLissage = float(ui.valLissage.displayText())    
        return (valLissage)         
    valCouche = nameCouche() # asks for a positional argument but 'self' doesnt work   

    def choixTraitement(self):
        ui.okLissage.clicked.connect(p.goLissage)

    def goLissage(self, valCouche):
        if ui.chkboxLissage.isChecked():
            print(valCouche) # result is False
            os.system(r'"C:\Program Files\FME\fme.exe" D:\Stelios\..... --MAX_NUM_POINTS {0}'.format(valCouche))
```

So I would like to use `valCouche` in `goLissage` method but it doesnt work.
I thought that `valCouche` would have the argument of `valLissage` but instead it gives False as a value.
I've tried different alternatives but still doesnt work.

Comment: OT but anyway: 1. your class name should be capitalized ("Projet", not "projet"), 2. "ui" should be an attribute (passed to the `__init__()` method), not a global, 3. the command called by `os.system()` and it's args should not be hardcoded (either make them settings or pass them to your class's `__init__()`).  Well, if you expect your code to be maintainable, that is...

Comment: Thanks. 1- I capitalized "Projet". 2- "ui" is a class Ui_Interface() 3- it will not be hardcoded when i am done, but i'm still in the early process.

Comment: You say '"ui" is a class Ui_Interface()' - which FWIW suggests it's an instance of this class but anyway : class, instance or module, it's still an object - but that's not the point... The point is to be able to substitute whatever 'ui' is with any other object having the same interface. Proper decoupling makes testable and maintainable code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to declare variabile in the `__init__` method (constructor) and then use it in your code

ex:

```
class projet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.valCouche = ''

    def nameCouche(self):
        valLissage = float(ui.valLissage.displayText())     
        return (valLissage)         


    def choixTraitement(self):
        ui.okLissage.clicked.connect(p.goLissage)

    def goLissage(self, valCouche):
        if ui.chkboxLissage.isChecked():
            self.valCouche = self.nameCouche() 
            print(self.valCouche) # result is False
            os.system(r'"C:\Program Files\FME\fme.exe" D:\Stelios\..... --MAX_NUM_POINTS {0}'.format(self.valCouche))
```

Comment: No, you don't have to declare variables in `__init__`; you can add a new attribute anywhere else just as easily as you can add one there.

Comment: @abarnert: you're technically right - but it's a good practice to "declare" (well, initialize, at least to a default value) expected instance attributes in the `__init__()`.

Comment: I think you are almost right. The trouble is, that you cannot use `valCouche` as a function-pointer to `nameCouche()` because the object and therefore `self` do not exist at the class declaration point (if it were a class variable like in the OPs code). Declaring `self.valCouche` in  `__init__` makes sense, because `self.valCouche` is a function pointer to a object function. However, it should be `self.valCouche = self.nameCouche` to follow the case of the OP example

Comment: @P.R.: That doesn't make any sense. Assuming by "function-pointer" you just mean a method object, `nameCouche()` is a _call_ of the method, not the method itself. And it clearly returns a `float`, not another callable. And the only thing he does with that value is print it out—which is a reasonable thing to do with a `float`, but usually pointless with a method.

Answer (score 3):

You've got multiple problems here.

First, if you write this in the middle of a class definition:

```
valCouche = nameCouche()
```

... you're creating a class attribute, which is shared by all instances, not a normal instance attribute.

Also, you're running this at class definition time. That means there *is* no `self` yet--there aren't any instances yet to be `self`--so you can't call a method like `nameCouche`, because you don't have anything to call it on.

What you want to do is call the method at instance initialization time, on the instance being initialized, and store the return value in an instance attribute:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.valCouche = self.nameCouche()
```

Then, when you want to access this value in another method later, you have to access it as `self.valCouche`.

---

If you make those changes, it will *work*. But your object model still doesn't make much sense. Why is `nameCouche` a method when it doesn't have anything to do with the object, and doesn't access any of its attributes? Maybe it makes sense as a `@staticmethod`, but really, I think it makes more sense just as a plain function outside the class. In fact, *none* of the code you've written seems to have anything to do with the class.

This kind of cram-everything-into-the-class design is often a sign that you're trying to write Java code in Python, and haven't yet really understood how Python does OO. You might want to read a good tutorial on Python classes. But briefly: if you're writing a class just to have somewhere to dump a bunch of vaguely-related functions, what you want is a module, not a class. If you have some reason to have instances of that class, and the functions all act on the data of each instance, then you want a class.

Comment: I think valCouche is supposed to be a function pointer, because the OP wants to check the `displayText()` which I assume to be dynamic

Comment: P.R. is right.
@abarnert thank you for your answer. I will modify some things. But here i've just put a small piece of my code, maybe that's why it looks weird and doesnt make muche sense. I'm definitely not a Python expert. I think i need classes, but i will have a closer look to 'modules'.

Comment: @P.R.: That doesn't make any sense. He's doing `valCouche = nameCouche()` in his attempted code, meaning he's attempting to _call_ the method, not just reference it. And he never attempts to call `valCouche` later; the only thing he does with it is `print` it, which is an odd thing to do with a method object.

Comment: @guy16: If you think you need a class, you should be able to answer these questions: What real-life or abstract object do instances of that class represent? What things does it know how to do, and what internal state does it have to do them with?

Comment: The print is just a verification process, to see if the value is correct ; it will be deleted afterwards. Well everything in that class is everything I need to run the GUI (all the objects, the connections..). Once again, i'm still a beginner in programming, i dont understand everything but i'm trying my best to do it the right way.

Answer (score -1):

you have to define an initialization function: def__init__(self)
defining valCouche as an instance attribute make it accessible on all the method so we have the following

```
class projet(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.valCouche = ''

    def nameCouche(self):
        self.valCouche =  float(ui.valLissage.displayText())

    @staticmethod #here there is no need for self so it is a method of class
    def choixTraitement():
        ui.okLissage.clicked.connect(p.goLissage)

    def goLissage(self):
        if ui.chkboxLissage.isChecked():
           print(self.valCouche) # result is False
           os.system(r'"C:\Program Files\FME\fme.exe" D:\Stelios\..... --MAX_NUM_POINTS {0}'.format(self.valCouche))
```

Comment: It's best to explain your code so that the asker understands your answer.